# Argument 'customerCtrl' is not aNaNunction, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a curious error that seems to suggest my controller is not being created properly. Can anyone explain? This is my first SPA app so I'm programming in the dark a little bit.

Here is my master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ibosApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>iBOS</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/scripts/route-config.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/acs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <ng-view/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my view template:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="customers" class="tab-pane fade active in top-buffer" ng-controller="customerCtrl">
        <form class="form-group">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-broker">Broker:</label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" id="customer-broker"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-town">Town:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-town"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-code">Code:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-code"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <button ng-click="search()" class="btn">Search</button>
                        <button ng-click="myCustomers()" class="btn">My customers</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-company-name">Company name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-company-name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-contact-name">Contact name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-contact-name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="customer-customer-id">Customer ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-customer-id"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('ibosApp', ['angular-bootstrap-select', 'ngRoute'])
        .controller("customerCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.loadBrokers = function() {
                    $http.get("/api/customers/getBrokers").success(function(data) {
                        $scope.brokers = data;
                    });
                }

                $scope.loadBrokers();
            }
    );
</script>
```

but I get the error "Argument 'customerCtrl' is not aNaNunction, got undefined" and the controller constructor is never called. Can anyone explain why?

M

**EDIT - more code**

Here is my route config...

```
angular.module("ibosApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/booking-system-template.html"
        });
    });
```

**EDIT - full stack trace of error**

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=ibosApp&p1=Error%3…20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4685%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: It would be good to see the app and ctrl definition

Comment: I think you are missing a matching ")" from .controller(

Comment: They're at the bottom of the second listing. Have yet to move them into a separate file.

Comment: where do you define the `$routeProviders` configs? you use a `<ng-view>` Directive but nowhere is the `$routeProvider`

Comment: I don't think I am missing a ')' Octav

Comment: wait, is the controller in the view defined? Have you tried to put it directly in the master page?

Comment: I have added $routeProviders code above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few things wrong.

1. You're *setting* `ibosApp` twice, i.e., `angular.module("ibosApp", ["ngRoute"])` and `angular.module("ibosApp", ['angular-bootstrap-select'])`

You should only do this once, with all of your dependencies:

```
angular.module("ibosApp", ['ngRoute', 'angular-bootstrap-select']);
```

...and then use the `getter` syntax, which is the same, without the second parameter:

```
angular.module('ibosApp')
```

2. You can't define controllers in the view like you're doing *unless* you re-compile your angular app.  It would be best to put your javascript into a separate file and include that script on your index page.  The reason this isn't working is because your angular app compiles one time, then you load the view and define the controller, but angular doesn't know about that control since it wasn't there when you compiled it.

So:

**app.js**

```
angular.module("ibosApp", ["ngRoute", "angular-bootstrap-select"])
 .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/booking-system-template.html"
    });
});
```

**customerCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('ibosApp').controller("customerCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.loadBrokers = function() {
                $http.get("/api/customers/getBrokers").success(function(data) {
                    $scope.brokers = data;
                });
            }

            $scope.loadBrokers();
        }
);
```

And your markup would be

```
// previous script tags
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="customerCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply Tom. I have done exactly as you suggest but now I am getting a [different error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=ibosApp&p1=Error%3…20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4685%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381))

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace

Comment: Full stack trace in question above

Comment: I don't think that's the full stack trace... but, make sure you're including the correct script for whatever `angular-bootstrap-select` is... I'm 90% sure that's where your problem is going to lie.

Comment: Yep, I've removed that dependency and it's now loading as expected. I'll have to investigate the drop down library (it's really rather good). Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Is your module only defined in the template? If that's the case that might be your problem, the app isn't initialized since ng-app can't find the module you're trying to load. I would begin with separating JavaScript and HTML to make it easier on yourself.

Comment: Thanks hochas, I have implemented it like Tom has suggested (below).